# URI not absolute when filename contains spaces

Tags: java, file, encoding, uri

With the URI, i want to return the path of files, but i have a problem with spaces (URI not absolute), to resolve this problem i found URLEncoder.Encode.

I need to use encoding with the code below:

```
new File(new URI(Path)).getAbsolutePath();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace the spaces, if you don't have other illegal characters.

```
new File(new URI(Path.replaceAll(" ", "%20"))).getAbsolutePath();
```